# Who will be under loss after the March update?

Tags: google-penguin-algorithm

Who will be under loss after the March update in the below scenarios?

Type 1: Site which gives nofollow link instead of ugc, follow, sponsored, etc
Type 2: Site which receives nofollow link instead of ugc, follow, sponsored, etc

Please let me know your updates.

Thanks

Comment: You tagged this as "Google Penguin algorithm" but I'm not aware of any penguin update that ever happened in March.  There is nothing on this list: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-algorithm-history/   Exactly Google update are you asking about?

Comment: You also mention `ugc` and `nofollow`, but Google made changes for those last September.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

First thing to perhaps highlight is that for ranking purposes, this is already live, the change in March is to them using links marked nofollow, ucg or sponsored for discovery, meaning that in the past google ignored links marked this way, from March, they may note the links and go and crawl them.

If anything the site that has nofollow, ugc, sponsored links pointed to them MIGHT get a boost, if google looks at these links and decides that hey, this is actually a useful link, we'll pass some value on.

The site that correctly marks up links will see no changes at all.

links without these attributes (follow links) will behave in the same way as before, the changes make no difference here.